# Differential equation solved without laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the following differential equation where $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$

$$y''+y=e^{-t^2}$$

Given that the laplace of $e^{-t^2}$ exists but without finding it, what is the solution to the differential equation?

Not sure how to solve this without using Laplace explicitly. I don't know much about alternative methods so if you can make your explanations relatively simple.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are to use Laplace, but you don't need to evaluate the Laplace transform. Leave the integral unsolved

Answer (score 1):

If $F$ is the LT of $y$ and $g$ is the LT of $e^{-t^2},$ you have $$ s^2F(s)+F(s) =g(s)\implies F(s) = \frac{g(s)}{s^2+1}.$$ So the solution is the inverse LT of $\frac{g(s)}{s^2+1}.$ That's about all you can say, I think, without more information about $g.$